# Non-uniqueness of solutions of an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For instance, consider the following initial value problem $$x'=3x^{2/3}, \ \ \ \ x(0)=0$$

This initial value problem has *infinitely* many solutions given by $$ x(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & t<c \\
(t- c)^3 & t \geq c
\end{cases} \ \ \ \ \ (*) $$ for any non-negative $c$. Picard's existence theorem says that the initial value problem $x'=f(x,t), x(t_0)=x_0$ has a *unique* solution if $f(x,t)$ is continuous at $(x_0,t_0)$ and Lipschitz continuous in $x$. So the non-uniqueness comes from the fact that $3x^{2/3}$ is not Lipschitz at $x=0$. But I was wondering why a student taking a basic undergrad course in differential equations is not able to get the totality of solutions (*) ? i.e. one proceeds like this  $$ \frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}dx=dt \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ \ x^{1/3}=t+C  $$ applying the initial condition we get $C=0$. So $$x(t)=t^3$$
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the derivation that the undergraduate student has found (which is sometime called *separation of variables*) they are assuming that $x\neq 0$. In fact the solution they find:
$$
x(t) = (t+C)^3
$$
is valid and unique in every point where $x(t)\neq 0$. The same undergraduate student, before dividing the equation by $x$, would check that they are not losing solutions. And they find, that
$$
x(t) = 0
$$
is in fact a solution.

Now they notice that solutions of the first kind can touch the solution $x=0$ and when this happens the derivatives of the two solutions agree. Hence they can merge the solutions together to get the general solution you wrote at the beginning.

Comment: I see that , but still I think that, without being taught by explicit examples, they would not be able to "glue" two solutions together. All I can expect to see is that they give a solution like $$x \equiv 0 \ \text{and} \ x = t^3$$ Now I realized that this was a gap in the differential equations course that I took some years ago.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a gap in many courses. I have seen books which write that the solution to $x'=2\sqrt x, x(0)=0$  is $x=t^2$. Which is not only inaccurate but completely wrong for $t<0$.